# Should my graphics card be running at a clock speed higher than the spec?

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a GeForce GTX 660 on my windows 7 computer. I have been having problems with certain games where it randomly freezes. I began monitoring using EVGA Precision X16 and I noticed that the clock is running between 1150 and 1200 but the [vendor specifications](https://www.evga.com/Products/pdf/02G-P4-2662.pdf) show the boost at 1111 Mhz. I'm wondering if this means that my GPU was manually overclocked above the vendors spec and if so how do I reset it?

**Update**:
After changing the power target to 110 within the Precision X16 software I was able to run my game with far fewer freezes occuring. The game ran for several hours without issue where it would normally freeze up multiple times within the span of an hour. However it did eventually freeze up again. The clock still hits speeds of 1163, so I'm still not sure whether it is normal for the GPU to surpass the max specification of 1111. I tried uploading a screenshot of the Precision X16 software but apparently I need 10 more reputation in order to do this.

**Update 2**:
I just wanted to close out this post with the answer that I found to the original question. It appears that the GPU clock can run faster than the advertised GPU boost number in the specification. The stock value for the boost clock is 1088 Mhz, the overclocked value from the vendor I purchased it from is 1111 Mhz, but I found run values of 1163 Mhz. This is because of the [Nvidia boost technology](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/gpu-boost-2/technology).

I have been able to significantly reduce the freezing that occurs by adjusting the Power Target setting to 110%, which eliminated needless throttling of the GPU caused by GPU power going above 100%. However, I believe that the computer case may not be an optimal design and may be contributing to the GPU getting to temperatures of 70 Celsius. This temperature is not harmful to the GPU but I believe it is the point at which the GPU again throttles back which in turn causes the game to freeze up.

Comment: You linked to the reference card not the card you actually have which comes over clocked, no, your problems are likely driver related

Comment: You are correct the actual information is [here](https://www.evga.com/Products/pdf/02G-P4-2662.pdf). This indicates that the upper limit is 1111. I'm still getting higher numbers when I monitor. Is this normal?

Comment: Have you installed the software that came with it that allows you to overclock it?

Comment: It was loaded as part of the initial installation, but i have not used it.

Comment: Load the program and verify what the settings are post a screenshot if you have too

Comment: I will do that for you Ram and thanks for trying to help. I think I might have found the problem though. I noticed in the monitoring data that GPU power seemed to get above 100 frequently. I did some research to understand what this meant. and found that that  my power target was set to 100%. As I understand it, this setting will throttle the cpu when it is reached, and the recommendation is to go to at least 110%.  I have not experienced any further problems since doing this. Crossing my fingers. I'll report back when I know more.

Comment: @Ramhound I tried loading an image but I am unable to do this. I'm not sure which settings you would like me to verify. There are multiple. There is a gauge which shows the GPU boost clock between 1000 and 1200 which would be about the 1111 area discussed in the specifications. If there is another setting I should report to you let me know. I'm going to open a ticket with EVGA to see if they can provide some insight.

Comment: Something worth considering is a lot of cards are factory overclocked - they're either processors binned to be faster or with better cooling. EVGA might have done that, which would explain the speed, but not the freezes

Comment: @JourneymanGeek In a reply to Ramhound I added a link to the specs for the EVGA card I have. It is overclocked but it says the boost is 1111 which I assumed was the max for the clock. Are you saying that my assumption is incorrect?  Totally possible since I'm definitely not a hardware guru. :P

Comment: @Ramhound I wanted you to know that I also was looking for driver related issues, but I have found nothing there yet. A clean install was done of the graphics drivers, I also tried removing any possible contention with sound drivers and logitech drivers but to no avail. Thanks again for your suggestions.

Comment: Just to provide more information for your second update. Nvidia Boost throttling your clocks slightly won't freeze your entire game and cause it to crash. All it does is provide draw extra power that is already available to increase clocks. If it hits the thermal limit, it will reduce power back slightly to stabilize the temperature below the limit.

If you think it's an airflow/case problem, take the sidepanels off your case for maximum airflow and see if you still get freezing.

Comment: @BenSampica I have been running the game without the panels on and I am not currently having issues, which is why I made the assumption I did. I won't say the problem is cleared yet because it can take some time before I will see a freeze. I've read in other forums where throttling can indeed cause a game to freeze and as I mentioned by setting the power target higher (reducing throttling, as I was getting numbers above 100%) I significantly reduced freezing (use to happen with minutes of playing the game). I'll report back if I learn something more.

Comment: @nydba Glad you're seeing better results. Hopefully it's fixed!

Comment: @BenSampica Thank you! I hope so too. This has been quite a learning experience for me if nothing else. I really appreciate the input from everyone. Thanks again.

Comment: @nydba Any news on if the problem has been fixed? It does seem like Precision is using the extra power to boost the clock. If the card is boosting higher than the specified manufacturer boost clock, perhaps a particular component in the graphics card is overheating (even though the measured temp of 70C isn't hot for a graphics card, maybe it is 'cooking' one particular chip). Let us know :)